# How to display custom vaildation error messages for API requests?

Tags: php, laravel, api

```
            try{
                $request->validate([
                    'aadhar' => 'required|digits:12|numeric',
                    'name' => 'required|string|max:511',
                    'dob' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
                    'address' => 'required|string',
                    'insuranceid' => 'required|digits_between:1,15|integer',
                    'password' => 'required|min:59|max:60',
                ]);
                }
            catch(Exception $error){
                    $message = $error->getMessage();
                    $status_code=400;
                    return response()->json(["message" => $message,"status_code" => $status_code]);
                }
```

This is my piece of code for the validation of the request parameters sent to an API. The documentation gives details only about custom error messages in case of a form request.

The validation errors give the default message "The given data was invalid" but I would like to know which of the parameter was invalid. How do I give custom validation error messages for API requests validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'password' => [
            'required',
            'confirmed',
            'between:8,55'
        ]
    ]);

    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return response()->json( [ 'errors' => $validator->errors() ], 400 );
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so it is only possible through an instance of the Validator facade or can the errors be displayed in spite of using the validate method?

Comment: If you look at these docs, there is an messages array as second parameter: https://devdocs.io/laravel~5.5/api/5.5/illuminate/http/request#method_validate

Comment: I referred the validation page in the docs, where such an example wasn't given. Didn't refer the parameters that the method can have. Thanks for the link and the answer!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, to decouple your code, you could use a [Form Request class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests). From the docs:

> For more complex validation scenarios, you may wish to create a "form
>   request". Form requests are custom request classes that contain
>   validation logic.

This class contains two methods:

**1 -** `rules`, the place where you specify your rules, it should return an array of rules.
**2 -** `authorize` that return a `boolean`,this method control who is allowed to perform this request. **By default is set to `false`**, so every call will be rejected.

So, in your case, it should be something like this:

First, create your custom Request class executing this artisan command in your console:

```
php artisan make:request CreateCustomObjectRequest
```

This wil create a new class under `app/Http/Requests`:

```
class CreateCustomObjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // Implement here your Auth validation, something like:
        return auth()->check();
        // or just return "true" if you want to take care of this anywhere else.
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'aadhar' => 'required|digits:12|numeric',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:511',
            'dob' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'address' => 'required|string',
            'insuranceid' => 'required|digits_between:1,15|integer',
            'password' => 'required|min:59|max:60',
        ];
    }
}
```

And then, in your controller, instead of inject a regular Request object, we are gonna use this custom Request object:

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateCustomObjectRequest;

// ...

    public function store(CreateCustomObjectRequest $request)
    {
        // the rest of your controller logic.
    }
```

**Now, the part you are really interested in.** To return errors in a json way you should add the next header when making a request:

```
Accept: Application/json
```

This header will tell Laravel that the output should be a json response, so it will convert it to json. Note that this will only work with the validation rules and when returning objects like `return $someObject`. To more further customization you shoud use something like:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $someObject], 200);
```

Comment: I tried implementing the validation of API requests through form requests and gave my custom error messages in the messages method of the form request class. But, what happened was, when the validate method found errors, the output that I received was "You are being redirected to http://localhost:8080". Instead of the errors being displayed, it redirected me to the default redirect page, just like when a redirect is required when a form has errors.

Comment: That's why you should add the header I mentioned on my response (Accept: application/json)

Comment: Oh, okay. So, the request from the client side must have that header?

Comment: Exactly. That header will tell Laravel that you want a response in that format. That header is also useful in other cases, for example when using Laravel Passport.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I earnestly want to upvote this answer, but wouldn't be able to due to less reputation.

Comment: Don't worry. I hope it help you in the future.